# Use .htaccess to make pretty URLs that expand abbreviation codes

Tags: htaccess, url, php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Yes, I know, there are tons of questions like this, but I can't find one which solves my problem so at cost of receiving downvotes I'm going to ask this again. Even a duplicate link may help me.

This is a job that I've never done before, I have this kind of URL `demo.html?code=IT-ROM-FCO` where:

- `IT` is the IATA code for *"Italy"*
- `ROM` is the IATA code for *"Rome"*
- `FCO` is the IATA code for *"Aeroporto di Roma Fiumicino"*.

I have to rewrite the above URL to display like this `airports/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino`, the strings for the result are coming from an API service.

I know the simple rewrite to change `products.php?id=7` to `products/7` but I never done such task (get an URL - retrieve some data in PHP w/ the given code - "pretty" print the new URL)

As I really don't know how to achieve this job I have no code example, sorry.

Comment: Does it have to be done in .htaccess?   For something this complicated it probably makes sense to pass the `airports/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino` into your web app and have it deal with the conversion.

Comment: How many substitutions do you have to deal with?   Is it just three codes (`IT`, `ROM`, and `FCO`)?   Are the dozens?  Hundreds?

Comment: I have 2 versions of the `code` parameter, the first is `code=IT-ROM` which shows all airports of Rome and there are about 9K cities... the full version is `code=IT-ROM-FCO` and shows data of a specified airport...about 16K of them.
I think I'm going to insert another parameter called `alias` in the URL so I can retrieve it in `.htaccess` and exclude the codes

Comment: 25,000 substitutions is far too many to specify in .htaccess.   It won't perform well enough.

Comment: Are you saying that I can not do it with two simple substitutions? One for the short vesrion and one for the full version?

Comment: Have you considered a URL like: `/IT-ROM-FCO/airports/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino`?   When the URL has both the code and the keywords, it is some of the best of both worlds.   It is easy to rewrite and it contains info that lets users see what it is about just by looking.   Similar to how this site has an ID and slug in the URL.

Comment: I have to ask confirmation to SEO specialist in my office but I think it could be done. So if I let an URL like `demo.html?code=IT-ROM-FCO&countryAlias=italy&cityAlias=Rome&airportAlias=aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino` I can easily convert it to `airports/IT-ROM-FCO/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino` with .htaccess?

Comment: Conversion in .htaccess has to go the other way around.   You get the pretty URL coming in and you have to convert into the codes that the web app uses.  If you have the codes in URL, you don't need to pass aliases to the web app at all, you can just ignore them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller can I ask you an example, maybe in an answer? P.s: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend keeping the codes in the URL.  There are some advantages to do so:

- Codes are easy to keep static.  Names of places often change over time.   If the codes are there you don't have to keep records of old names and implement redirects based on old names.
- It is easy to rewrite when the data you need for the web-app is in the URL.  .htaccess is not great for lookup tables.  Putting 25,000 rewrite rules into .htaccess would be a performance killer.

I'd recommend using a URL like: `/IT-ROM-FCO/airports/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino`  You would use the following rewrite rule to put the codes into the parameter and remove the slug:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([A-Z]+-[A-Z]+(-[A-Z]+)?).* /demo.html?code=$1 [L]
```

That would take any URL that has two or three abbreviations at the beginning and put them into the code parameter.   That should support either your `code=IT-ROM` or `code=IT-ROM-FCO` cases you mentioned in the comments.

Then when you generate URLs on your site, put the pretty version in the hrefs:

```
<a href="/IT-ROM-FCO/airports/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino">
```

You'll also need to "canonicalize" your URLs.   The URL `/IT-ROM-FCO/foo-bar` will then show the same content.   It is probably easiest to solve this by using a meta link rel canonical tag in the head of the page with the pretty URL.  That will tell Google which version is your preferred URL.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/IT-ROM-FCO/airports/italy/rome/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino">
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Stephen!! Tomorrow I will talk with SEO specialist and implement your solution!

Comment: You might also want to consider lowercasing the codes.   Mixed case URLs don't always work very well.   Rather, they work fine, but some software tries to lowercase the whole URL.  Crawlers and content management systems, mostly.   That can cause lots of crawl errors.

Comment: Sorry Stephen but it seems I can't make it work. The full URL I have is `http://webpartner.it/orariovoli/aeroporti.html?code=IT-ROM-FCO` and should be changed to `http://webpartner.it/orariovoli/aeroporti/fco/aeroporto-di-roma-fiumicino` (new URL asked by SEO specialist, but it doesn't work with the older version)

Comment: One thing to note: the site I am working on is made with Joomla! and I suppose something is interferring with my htaccess

Comment: Rewrite rules won't prevent old URLs from working.  They just make new URLs work in addition.   The easiest way to prevent Google from using the old URLs is to implement the canonical tags.

Comment: Joomla's [rewrite rules](https://docs.joomla.org/Preconfigured_htaccess) rewrite all URLs to *index.php*.   This is a very common *front controller* design pattern for content management systems.   You might either have to rewrite your URLs to *index.php* as well, or remove the "last" flag (`[L]`) that I suggested so that Joomla's rewrite rules take effect after it.